# Copy constructor is not called in the for_each loop

Tags: c++

Trying to learn C++ and I was practicing for_each loop and lambdas. I am writing a simple example where a members of a vector are constructed in the for_each loop. However the copy constructor is not called where I expect.
The code works but I don't understand why?
I also tried deleting the move constructor. But that gave me error at when I create `l`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
public:
    Point (int x, int y):x (x), y (y)
  {
    cout << "paramterized constructor" << endl;
  }
  Point () = default; 
  Point (const Point & p)
  {
    cout << "copy constructed" << endl;
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
  }
  void print () const
  {
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
  }
};

int
main ()
{

  std::vector < Point > my (5); 
  cout << "vector created" << endl;
  int count = 0;
  auto l = Point (5, 6);//RH paramterized constructed and then copy constructed to left? 
  std::for_each (my.begin (), my.end (),[&](Point & p)
         {
            p = Point (++count, count);//p not copy constructed?
            count++;
         });        
  std::for_each (my.begin (), my.end (),[](const Point & p)
         {
            p.print ();
         });

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
default constructor
default constructor
default constructor
default constructor
default constructor
vector created
paramterized constructor
copy constructed
paramterized constructor
paramterized constructor
paramterized constructor
paramterized constructor
paramterized constructor
1 0
3 2
5 4
7 6
9 8
```

Comment: `p = Point (++count, count);` invokes a copy-assignment operator, not a copy constructor.

Comment: You ALWAYS need to have a copy assignment whenever you have a copy constructor.

Comment: *"when I create `l`"* -- possibly the worst variable name to use. It's bad style to use non-descriptive variable names. Among the non-descriptive names, the single-letter names are particularly bad. And among the single-letter names, `l` is easy to mistake for `1` in many fonts.

Comment: Do you understand why `default constructor` is output five times before `vector created`?

Comment: @JaMiTThis is for the vector being created and each one default constructed. Reading this and the answer posted later  I understand that the the `p` are not constructed  in the for_Each loop but when the vector is created.

Comment: @JaMiTSorry I was just testing thing and left it their. Should have changed that name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not constructing anything. Construction happens once. That's *copy assignment*.

```
p = Point(++count, count);
```

We can't construct `p`, since it already exists. Construction implies bringing something *into* existence. As a real-world analogy, it's like if I took you to a finished house and then declared that I was going to build that exact house on that exact lot.

Instead, this first invokes the `Point(int, int)` constructor (since you passed it two integers), then we *assign* that temporary to `p` with a copy assignment operator. The copy assignment operator, like many things in C++, is automatically generated if possible, unless you create one yourself. The syntax to make your own is as follows.

```
Point& operator=(const Point& p) {
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    return *this;
}
```

By convention we return `*this` as a reference from copy assignment, so that assignment chaining (`a = b = c`) works like C++ programmers expect.

If you define a copy constructor, you should also define a destructor and a copy assignment operator. If you implement move construction, you also need to implement move assignment. This is called the [Rule of Zero/Three/Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and I strongly recommend you read that linked question and answer, as it contains a *lot* of valuable information.

You'll also want to look into [the copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), which can make implementing the copy assignment easier (and prevents code duplication between it and the copy constructor).

Finally, there's a reason it's called the "Rule of **Zero**/Three/Five". Most often, the answer to "which of these five methods should I implement" is "zero". Your class contains two integers. It doesn't do any complex resource allocation, and it doesn't use raw pointers. So the best situation for you is to just not implement any of them. C++ will make all of the following for you, and for your `Point` class (and *many* classes in C++ that don't use raw pointers), it'll simply be correct.

- Destructor
- Copy constructor
- Copy assignment
- Move constructor
- Move assignment